# Remove an element from unbalanced binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have been wanting to write `remove()` method for my Binary Search Tree (which happens to be an array representation). But before writing it, I must consider all cases. Omitting all cases (since they are easy) except when the node has two children, in all the explanations I have read so far, most of the cases I see remove an element from an already balanced binary search tree. In the few cases where I have seen an element being removed from an unbalanced binary search tree, I find that they balance it through zigs and zags, and then remove the element.

**Is there a way that I can possibly remove an element from an unbalanced binary search tree without having to balance it beforehand?**

**If not, would it be easier to write an AVL tree (in array representation)?**

Comment: Are you using array index offsets in each tree node or are you remembering what tree level you're at and using multiplication to find the index? If the second, I believe your tree must be balanced.

Comment: Array contains nodes, nodes contain the data and the indexes of their children. -1 if no child present.

Comment: I was wrong about needing balancing anyway. An unbalanced tree with fixed position array nodes just wastes space but still works.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to balance it, but you do need to recursively go down the tree performing some swaps here and there so you actually end up with a valid BST.

Deletion of a node with 2 children in an (unbalanced) BST: (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion))

> Call the node to be deleted N. Do not delete N. Instead, choose either its in-order successor node or its in-order predecessor node, R. Copy the value of R to N, then recursively call delete on R until reaching one of the first two cases.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>Deleting a node with two children from a binary search tree. First the rightmost node in the left subtree, the inorder predecessor 6, is identified. Its value is copied into the node being deleted. The inorder predecessor can then be easily deleted because it has at most one child. The same method works symmetrically using the inorder successor labelled 9.</sub>

Although, why do you want an unbalanced tree? All operations on it take on it take longer (or at least as long), and the additional overhead to balance doesn't change the asymptotic complexity of any operations. And, if you're using the array representation where the node at index `i` has children at indices `2i` and `2i+1`, it may end up fairly sparse, i.e. there will be quite a bit of wasted memory.

Comment: Well, it's an assignment and though I'd love to make it perfect, time is short, so I won't really make it a self-balancing BST, unless required to, which I am not.